# Why is $x(x-9)=x^2-9x$ and not $x^2-9$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

the expression $x(x-9)$ is resolved in the manner
$$x(x-9)=x^2-9x$$
but why not like this?
$$x(x-9)=x^2-9$$
where does the $9x$ come from?

Answer (score 5):

Remember the distributive law
$$
a(b+c) = ab + ac .
$$

In your expression, $a=x$, $b=x$ and $c = -9$.

Then $x$ times $-9$ is rewritten as $-9x$.

Answer (score 2):

$$x(x-9)$$
By the Distributive Law
$$x^2-9x$$

Here's a short "proof" to show that you can't derive $x^2-9$ from $x(x-9)$.

$$\text{Proof by Contradiction}$$

Assume that

$$x(x-9) = x^2-9$$

Further, we will say that

$$f(x)=x(x-9)$$ and $$g(x) = x^2-9$$

If $$x(x-9) = x^2-9$$

then $$f(x)=g(x)$$

Because $$f(x)=g(x), f(0) = g(0)$$

This, however, is not the case

$$0(0-9) \neq 0^2-9$$

$$ \therefore f(x) \neq g(x)$$

Comment: Your "short proof" could be just one line long: the equation fails for $x=0$.

Comment: Ha, note taken.

Comment: You don't need all that stuff defining $f$ and $g$. Just the next to last line.

Answer (score 2):

What's the area of the dark green rectangle? The area of the light green rectangle is $A = x(x-9)$, but it's also the difference between the square $x^2$ and the dark green rectangle. What is this difference? Can you see where the distributive property [e.g. $a(b-c) = ab - ac$] comes from?

[image]